# Insert case when into table from joined table

Tags: sql, database

I'm new to SQL and I'm having some trouble solving a problem. I'm rewriting a script where I can match with customers who have received an email. Previously I have been using session tables as below:

```
DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE EMAIL_SENDS
        (
        ACCOUNT_NUMBER      INT
        )
WITH REPLACE
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS
;

INSERT INTO SESSION.EMAIL_SENDS
SELECT      ACCOUNT_NUMBER
FROM        SENT_DATA A
    JOIN    MAIN_TABLE B
        ON  A.CLIENT_ID_SUBKEY = B.CUST_ID
        OR  A.CLIENT_ID_SUBKEY = B.OLD_ID
WHERE       SEND_ID = 123456
GROUP BY    ACCOUNT_NUMBER
;
```

Then when pulling the data I have just used CASE WHEN C.ACCOUNT_NUMBER IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END joining the MAIN_TABLE with the EMAIL_SENDS to flag who has and hasn't received the email.

However I would like to improve the process, and add a column to the MAIN_TABLE stating who has received an email and who hasn't.

This is my script so far:

```
ALTER TABLE MAIN_TABLE
ADD EMAILED INT
;

INSERT INTO MAIN_TABLE
SELECT      EMAILED
CASE WHEN   ACCOUNT_NUMBER IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    FROM    (SENT_DATA A
            JOIN    MAIN_TABLE B
            ON  A.CLIENT_ID_SUBKEY = B.CUST_ID
            OR  A.CLIENT_ID_SUBKEY = B.OLD_ID
            WHERE       SEND_ID = 123456
            GROUP BY    ACCOUNT_NUMBER
            )
;
```

As I'm new to SQL I'm not able to figure out where I'm going wrong (even though it's probably obvious to anyone proficient at it).

Comment: share your table structure ....your main table having two columns ?? EMIALED, ACCOUNT_NUMBER

Comment: Are you sure you want `INSERT INTO MAIN_TABLE`, and not `UPDATE MAIN_TABLE`?

Answer (score 0):

try this. replace column names from main table to  with this **(EMAILED,ACCOUNT_NUMBER)**

```
INSERT INTO MAIN_TABLE (EMAILED,ACCOUNT_NUMBER)
SELECT      EMAILED,
CASE WHEN   ACCOUNT_NUMBER IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    FROM    (SENT_DATA A
            JOIN    MAIN_TABLE B
            ON  A.CLIENT_ID_SUBKEY = B.CUST_ID
            OR  A.CLIENT_ID_SUBKEY = B.OLD_ID
            WHERE       SEND_ID = 123456
            GROUP BY    ACCOUNT_NUMBER
            )
;
```